# How to build a pagination API in Yii 1.x using CPagination

Tags: php, yii, pagination

I'm new to yii. Currently I am building an API for some project. I managed to get all data from the database and sent as a response to the front end. Now there is an enhancement that I should limit the results outputted per page. So Pagination. I read a lot on CPagination in yii and no matter what I tried I'm getting a 500 internal server error. This is my codes;

```
    public function actionIndex()
{
    //getting page number from front end
    $request = file_get_contents('php://input');

    if (is_null($request)) {
        $page = 1;
    } else {
        $input = json_decode($request, true);
        $page = $input['page'];
    }

    //Criteria sorting templates by id DESC
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 'id DESC';

    //Number of rows returned
    $count = TblTemplate::model()->count($criteria);

    //Templates per page
    $perPage = 2;

    //Calculating the offset
    $offset = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $perPage) - $perPage : 0;

    $pages = new CPagination($count);
    $pages->pageSize = $perPage;
    $pages->offset   = $offset;
    $pages->applyLimit($criteria);

    //fetching all templates    
    $templates = TblTemplate::model()->findAll($criteria);

    $response = [];

    //Fetching all array - filtering through the cluster
    foreach ($templates as $template) {
        $response[] = [
            'id'      => $template->id,
            'name'    => $template->name,
            'email'   => $template->email,
            'content' => $template->content 
        ];
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why not trying `offset` and `limit` in `CDbCriteria`

Comment: Let me try that, but from yii docs the pageSize and offset must be on the object of the Cpagination

Comment: I added offset to the criteria but the offset is not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change It as: -

```
    $perPage = 2;
    $offset = ($page > 1) ? ($page * $perPage) - $perPage : 0;

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->order = 'id DESC';
    $criteria->limit=$perPage;
    $criteria->offset=$offset;

    $templates = Users::model()->findAll($criteria);
```